# How to generate executable across platforms

Tags: installation

in case i have a source code and an api to generate windows executable version, is there any possibility or any easy approach to convert it into something that can be executed across Linux /mac or Solaris platforms?

Comment: Recompile it into the proper executable format for each of those platforms. This is not something done through your installer.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Do you have source code, or just an executable file?  What does the executable do?  If it computes the first n prime numbers, that's very different from, say, scanning the operating system registry. Calls to system APIs can be very system-specific.

Comment: yes @KenWhite i am trying to explore an easy way to convert them.

Comment: The *only* way to convert them is to compile them into the proper format for each platform, fix any issues, and test on each platform. There is no alternative.

Comment: @Buggieboy sorry, i updated the query desc, i mean that i have a source code, which can be converted using an executable file, I am trying or rather in search of api, which can actually have a good compatibility to generate according to operating system selected

Comment: cool @KenWhite , thank you , i shall still continue to research it, will update you in case i find one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is in a .NET language, there are [online](https://www.varycode.com/) and [offline](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/) translators that can convert the code to Java.

This is just language translation, and doesn't convert the API calls, but it would be a first step in the process.

Another way to handle the problem would be to choose a cloud-based web service or [bridge](http://jnbridge.com/) solution.  If you have a significant amount of program logic, exposing APIs in this way would allow you to maintain much of the code in its existing language, while making it invocable on other platforms.

Comment: Glad you find it helpful, @Revanth.